# When static routing is preferred instead of dynamic routing protocols?

Tags: ip, wireless

Could anyone describe what is this? i'm little bit confused about this meaning.

Comment: Please make it clear what you want to understand

Comment: It look like you copy pasted the line from somewhere and asking a question without giving any reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are mainly three advantage of static routing over dynamic :-

Predictability: If you change your network design and layout and suffer from a device failure, static routes do not change. You always know the path your data will take

Network bandwidth overhead: Static routing has zero overhead, whereas all dynamic routing protocols have some degree of overhead. For example, on a network with 200 segments, the router will send updates from each interface every 30 seconds, and those updates are about 3KB of data. Over the course of a day, this traffic adds up.

Easy to configure: This issue is relative, depending on the size of your network.

Also , dynamic routing uses more CPU on routers and thus , small routers will
suffer performance .

so if you have less bandwidth , you certainly don't wanna loose them by using  dynamic 
routing